# If I join a war zone using an Ubuntu VM, can others on the war zone breach my network?

Tags: network

I am getting into the area of hobby exploitation on crack-me systems. So far, I have been playing through overthewire’s Bandit crack-me. One thing that interests me, overthewire has a war zone, which they advertise as a network where you can hack anything. Their warning: use a VM. I have an Ubuntu VM that I can back up, and I would like to join this war zone. My biggest concern is security. Is there any way anyone in that network could attack my home network outside of the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your VM is accessible to other participants, it could potentially be attacked and/or compromised. Once the VM is compromised, it can trivially be used to attack the rest of your network.

While this may not be likely for a default install with no services running, be careful what services you expose (if any). Like the site says, a properly configured firewall should prevent most issues.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I’ll be contacting the site community and looking in further.